# C# Linq OrderBy based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a foreach loop that I want to change:

`foreach (var line in lines.OrderBy(x=> x.ColA))`

If a condition is met, then instead of ordering by ColA, I want to order by ColB.

I know this could be done like the following:

```
var orderLines = new List<OrderLines>();
if (condition)
    orderLines = lines.OrderBy(x => x.ColB).ToList();
else
    orderLines = lines.OrderBy(x => x.ColA).ToList(); ;

foreach (var line in orderLines)
```

But I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Depends on the condition. What is it?

Comment: @juergend the condition is check to see what program created the Order Lines. For example, if (program == "OrderEntry") then Order By Column B otherwise I want it to Order By Column A.

Comment: @SamoanProgrammer Does `lines.OrderBy(x => condition?x.ColA:x.ColB).ToList()` not meet your desired?

Comment: @TấnNguyên no sorry, I tried that and get an error because ColA is a string and ColB is an int.

Comment: The way you have done it is clear and understandable. Leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mjwills

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T> / IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet-iqueryablet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several solutions.

(1) Don't do the `ToList()` before your foreach, only create the IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<OrderLines> orderLines = condition ?
    lines.OrderBy(orderLine => orderLine.ColB) :
    lines.OrderBy(orderLine => orderLine.ColA);

foreach(OrderLine orderlLine in orderLines) {...}
```

(2) If you will be using this on several locations, consider to create an extension method. This way your method looks like any other LINQ method.
See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderBy(
    this IEnumerable<OrderLine> source,
    bool condition)
{
    return condition ?
    lines.OrderBy(orderLine => orderLine.ColB) :
    lines.OrderBy(orderLine => orderLine.ColA);
}
```

Usage:

If operator checks chexBox1, sort by colB, else sort by colA:

```
IEnumerable<OrderLine> lines = ...
foreach(var sortedOrderLine in lines.OrderBy(this.CheckBox1.IsChecked))
{
    ...
}
```

Because it is an extension method of `IEnumerable<OrderLine>`, you can even intertwine it with other LINQ methods:

```
var result = lines.Where(orderLine => orderLine.Date.Year >= 2020)
                  .OrderBy(this.checkBox1.IsChecked)
                  .Select(orderLine => new
                  {
                       Id = orderLine.Id,
                       Price = orderLine.Price,
                  });
```

But all in all, it doesn't save you a lot of code. The only advantage would be if you would use it in a lot of methods. In that case, a change in how you want to OrderBy condition would have to be changed in only one place. But again: if you expect to use it in one place, moving it to a separate method might not help readers to understand what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough comment @Harald Coppoolse

Answer (score 2):

That is probably about as good as it gets.

Remember that behind that lambda expression magic happens which (effectively) binds to a `Comparer<T>` where T depends on the type of the columns being compared.

To make this more terse might make it less efficient.  Specifically converting and comparing strings makes it both slower and can get you into trouble (ints sort to 1,2,3,...10,11,... vs their strings to "1","10","11",..."19","2","20","21"...).

A "one-liner" is only **elegant** if it's behaviour is obvious, otherwise it is **obfuscated**.

Your code is fine.  (IMO;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlanK

Answer (score 0):

Install `NuGet` `System.Linq.Dynamic` and you can pass `property` name as `string` to `OrderBy` like below.

Usage `list.AsQueryable().OrderBy("PropertyName1 SortOrder, ropertyName SortOrder")`. Where `PropertyName` will be `ColA`  `ColB`. And `SortOrder` will be `ASC` `DESC`.

1. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;`
2. `foreach (var line in lines.AsQueryable().OrderBy(condition ? "ColB" : "ColA")`

---

For `.Net Core` install `NuGet` `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`.

1. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;`
2. `foreach (var line in lines.AsQueryable().OrderBy(condition ? "ColB" : "ColA")`

---

For a better practice rather than providing `PropertyName` as string use `nameof(Class.Property)` like in your case `nameof(OrderLines.ColA)`. So in case you change `ColA` property it will show `Build`error and you will not get `run time exception`.

- `foreach (var line in lines.AsQueryable().OrderBy(condition ? nameof(OrderLines.ColB) : nameof(OrderLines.ColA))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Karan but I'm not too keen

Answer (score 0):

As @AlanK have mentioned, the closest we can get for simplifying `OrderBy` would be something like:

```cs
Func<OrderLines, string> selector = (orderLine) => condition ? orderLine.ColB : orderLine.ColA;

List<OrderLines> orderLines = lines.OrderBy(selector);
```

provided both `ColA` and `ColB` are of same data type. Otherwise it wouldn't be efficient due to the overhead of data type conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Zephyr